# I'm Trying to Get a File object using an intent requesting an openable content

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a file object using an intent requesting an openable content.

So I will get from the intent a content URI string.
And I'm trying to figure out how to get a file object from it.
I saw example how to transform it to a file descriptor but haven't seen a way to make it into a file.

The result part which is required to send a File object to a method:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == EXPORT_PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Export File Chooser returned a result
            Uri returnUri = data.getData();
            File parmeter = ???? <=== getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(returnUri, "r");
```

The request for the File:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File"),
            EXPORT_PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm Trying to Get a File object using an intent requesting an openable content.

That is not possible in any reliable fashion.

This is akin to saying "I'm trying to get a File object using an HTTP URL from a Web server". While the Web server has a file, you do not have direct file server access to that server. You can get a stream, and create your own file out of that stream.

Similarly, with a `ContentProvider`, [a `Uri` is not a `File`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). Whether you use `openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver`, or get the `FileDescriptor` and open a stream on that, you need to consume the content as a stream.

After all, there is no requirement that the content be stored in a regular file in the first place, let alone one that you can access. The content may be in an encrypted file, in a BLOB column in a database, etc.

Comment: Thanks - I guessed I might need to create a file - whats the best way to create the File from the input stream?
If I'm asking for A file URI can get the file in that case?

Comment: @jBOB: "whats the best way to create the File from the input stream?" -- open a `FileOutputStream` on your desired file, then read bytes from the `InputStream` and write them to the `FileOutputStream`. "If I'm asking for A file URI can get the file in that case?" -- it will be your own file, wherever you choose to write it (e.g., `getFilesDir()`).